# Material ui autocomplete issue with default value in React

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, react-redux, material-ui

I'm using redux-form with material ui autocomplete field.

What I need to do is:

when page load autocomplete value would be empty .

When user start to type and reach to 3 character I want to call API and the result of that API I want to show as autocomplete dataSource.

What I have tried:

I tried to not set dataSource and in seconde try I set dataSource={} in both the case I got same error message:

> Failed prop type: The prop `dataSource` is marked as required in `AutoComplete`, but its value is `undefined`.**

Home.js class code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import AutoComplete from 'material-ui/AutoComplete';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Home extends Component {

renderAutoComplete = ({
                          input,
                          label,
                          meta: {touched, error},
                          children,
                          ...custom
                      }) => (
    <AutoComplete
        floatingLabelText={label}
        errorText={touched && error}
        {...input}
        onChange={(event, index, value) => input.onChange(value)}
        children={children}
        {...custom}
    />

)

render() {

    const startDate = new Date();

    const {handleSubmit} = this.props;

    return (

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>


            <div>
                <Field name="Origin_1" label="FROM" component={this.renderAutoComplete} dataSource={}/>
            </div>



            <div>
                <button type="submit">
                    Submit
                </button>
            </div>

        </form>

    );

}

}

const LogInForm = reduxForm({
form: 'MaterialUiForm', // a unique identifier for this form
validate
})(Home);
export default connect(mapStateTOProps, {getCity})(LogInForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**OP question is for old (v0) version of MUI**

From the [demo](https://v0.mui.com/#/components/auto-complete) and [source code comments](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v0.x/src/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.js#L60), you can see that value for the `dataSourse` property need to be an array:

```
/**
 * Array of strings or nodes used to populate the list.
 */
 dataSource: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
```

so you can do the following:

1. Set initial value of the `dataSource` as empty array
2. Do the API call when the length of inputed value will be more like 3 symbols
3. Update `dataSource` property on api responce callback

Also keep in mind that if you will use the array of objects for the value of `dataSourse`, each object need to have 'text' and 'value' keys:

```
const dataSource = [
  {text: 'Some Text', value: 'someFirstValue'},
  {text: 'Some Text', value: 'someSecondValue'},
];
```

or additional dataSourceConfig for mapping:

```
const dataSourceCustomKeys = [
  {textKey: 'Some Text', valueKey: 'someFirstValue'},
  {textKey: 'Some Text', valueKey: 'someSecondValue'},
];
const dataSourceConfig = {
  text: 'textKey',
  value: 'valueKey',
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The AutoComplete has a property called OnUpdateInput. it works similar to the keyup property. 
The function signature would be as:-
`function(searchText: string, dataSource: array, params: object) => void` 
 searchText would be the argument that you should pass to make a validation.

Create a function and pass an argument and check whether the argument.length>=4.
eg:

`check(query){
  if(query>=4){
   //call API or pass it to actions and then to the reducer and then API
  }`